# Парсинг сайта на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Только начал изучать python, решил сделать парсинг. 
с 'обычными' сайтами худо-бедно получается.
Но сейчас пытаюсь спарсить сайт https://www.fonbet.ru/#!/products/addresses/
Хочу отсюда получить список городов и их адреса, но стопарюсь при попытке просто спарсить html страницу.
Подозреваю, что все из-за #! в урле.
так ли это ? и можно это обойти ?

Comment: Добавьте пример с вашим кодом,что уже получилось и где возникают трудности

Answer (score 3):

Ваши данные погружаются через Ajax. 
Такие сайты парсят либо на Selenium (долго и медленно), либо ищут запросы, которые ушли и делают точно такие же на requests или на других библиотеках для запросов.

Список городов грузится отсюда: `https://clientsapi31.bkfon-resource.ru/shopAPI/api/v1.2/city/`

А список адресов отсюда: `https://clientsapi11.bkfon-resource.ru/shopAPI/api/v1.2/shop/?city=Москва&olen=999&format=json`

Достаточно выполнить похожие запросы requests и получить json. И Beautiful Soup не нужен

Comment: спасибо за Вашу подсказку очень помогло. только небольшой вопрос: а где Вы взяли урлы, откуда грузятся данные ? что-то не могу найти.

Comment: @FiodarRusakevich перед тем как пройти на сайт, откройте в браузере режим разработчика, перейдите на вкладку Сеть -> XHR и только потом грузите страницу, потом просмотрите все полученные запросы, и посмотрите у них ответ

Comment: получилось. спасибо за объяснения ? но я так понимаю, что это не на всех сайтах можно провернуть ?  к примеру мне надо узнать координаты с сайта https://koleso.ru/shops/, то это только через библиотеку urllib.request

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вы не используете header-ы. Обычно сайты блокируют доступ при подозрении на наличие парсинга. Сделайте вот так.

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
s.headers.update = ({
"""
    Сюда впишите ваш User-Agent, он находится в Network, 
    кликнув по любому data-request-у, на скриншоте замазан.
"""
})
```

Далее

```
r = requests.get('https://www.fonbet.ru/#!/products/addresses/')
print(r.text)
```

И будет вам HTML страница.

[image: User-Agent]

Comment: не будет этих данных, так как они подгружаются через ajax

Comment: Я написал решение популярной проблемы при парсинге. Тем более я указал, что так парсится HTML страница. "И будет вам HTML страница."

И да, исходный код HTML выдает на выходе.

Я не преследовал цель спарсить список городов. Внимательнее прочтите.